# How can I change the value of specified key? | discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I will reask this question because I'm not that good at explaining also I'm not English.
So I want to change the value of this key called "status" and these key values are "online". I have this in my `config.json`.

```js
{
    "status": "online"
}
```

So I am trying to replace the key's value. But I can't find it on the internet. I used fs and it didn't work. I really need someone to help me. I'm new to JS, I'm struggling with this problem over 2 hours. Here is the command of that I made, I'm using `discord.js` currently.

```js
...else if(args[0] === "idle"){
                const embed = {
                "title": "Status changed!",
                "description": "Set to \'idle\'.",
                "timestamp":  message.createdTimestamp,
                "color": 33023,
                "author": {
                  "name": message.author.tag,
                  "icon_url": message.author.avatarURL
                }
              };
        message.channel.send({embed}) 
        bot.user.setStatus('idle')
        //I'm trying to replace the config.json's key's value in this line.
        }

            else if(args[0] === "dnd"){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fs` you can do all your reading and writing as follows

Read from your config file and store the results.

```js
var configs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path/to/config.json"));
```

To write to your config file with your updated configs you can do the following

```js
    // Update your key value and write to the file to update.
    configs["status"] = "idle";
    const json = JSON.stringify(configs);
    fs.writeFile("path/to/config.json", json, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @S0me0n3-1 Please update the OP with the structure of your `config.json` file or provide an error to give some insight on the issue. The code I've provided you runs as intended on my end.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't understand that well.

Comment: @S0me0n3-1 You need to update your original post with more information so we have a better understanding as to why my code snippet isn't working. Either the file isn't being parsed properly due to the structure of your config file not being fully exposed to us or you have an error occurring causing the code to fail. Either way we need more information in the original post. As I said, the code snippet I posted works as intended on my end with all information you've provided.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not english.